# SpriteKit: physics polygon error

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

I am trying to initialize a `SKPhysicsBody` with a Polygon from a `CGPath`.
It is meant to look like this:
[image: star polygon]

My code CGPath is configured like this:

```
-(CGPathRef)GetStarPath{



    //Draw Object 1
    {
        //Create Path
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPoint pos = CGPointMake(177, 184.42); //Center Position
        CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, pos.x, pos.y); //Transform of object
        { //SubPath 0
            CGFloat d[] = {-3.0518e-05,-14.924,-3.0518e-05,-14.924,4.8492,-5.0988,4.8492,-5.0988, 4.8492,-5.0988,4.8492,-5.0988,15.692,-3.5232,15.692,-3.5232, 15.692,-3.5232,15.692,-3.5232,7.8462,4.125,7.8462,4.125, 7.8462,4.125,7.8462,4.125,9.6983,14.924,9.6983,14.924, 9.6983,14.924,9.6983,14.924,-9.1553e-05,9.8256,-9.1553e-05,9.8256, -9.1553e-05,9.8256,-9.1553e-05,9.8256,-9.6986,14.924,-9.6986,14.924, -9.6986,14.924,-9.6986,14.924,-7.8463,4.1249,-7.8463,4.1249, -7.8463,4.1249,-7.8463,4.1249,-15.692,-3.5234,-15.692,-3.5234, -15.692,-3.5234,-15.692,-3.5234,-4.8492,-5.0989,-4.8492,-5.0989, -4.8492,-5.0989,-4.8492,-5.0989,-3.0518e-05,-14.924,-3.0518e-05,-14.924 };
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &trans, d[0], d[1]);
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, &trans, d[i*8+2], d[i*8+3], d[i*8+4], d[i*8+5], d[i*8+6], d[i*8+7]);
            }
            CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
        }

        return path;
    }



}
```

But xcode throws some weird exception:

> Assertion failed: (edge.LengthSquared() > 1.19209290e-7F *
>   1.19209290e-7F), function Set, file /SourceCache/PhysicsKit/PhysicsKit-4.6/PhysicsKit/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp,
>   line 176.

(exception breakpoint stops at `[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:star_path];`)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the underlying Box2d error message states that one of your dimensions is simply too small to handle. 
Second, creating a star-shaped body will result in unexpected behaviour - as it states in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html), `bodyWithPolygonFromPath:` will only accept convex paths for polygons (no angles over 180 degrees inside the polygon - your star has 5 of them). It should also have no self-intersections and the winding is expected to be counter-clockwise.

If the stars are small enough, you can try using a circular physics body (`bodyWithCircleOfRadius:`) underneath as an approximation. If you insist on having a star object, you can try adding several physics bodies as children to a single node to have a star-shaped body: one pentagon and 5 triangles attached to it.

Comment: all right,thanks. Is this a common restriction in physic engines?

Comment: These are essentially restrictions particular to Box2d, which is integrated into Sprite Kit (although Box2d had a tighter restriction of 8 vertices per polygon, as far as I can remember).